Preparing for the company to breach the terms of the CC-BY-SA license
I am expecting that at some point in the future and possibly quite soon, the company will breach the terms of the CC-BY-SA licence that I grant to them as a content creator.
As is my right, when this breach happens, I want to formally revoke the licence I granted to the company to use my content and to have my content removed from various stackexchange sites.
What wording could I use in my network profile that becomes active and revokes the license I granted when this breach occurs?

You don't grant SE a CC-BY-SA license, you grant everyone else that license. SE gets a near limitless non-revocable license. "[...] you grant Stack Overflow the perpetual and irrevocable right and license to access, use, process, copy, distribute, export, display and to commercially exploit such Subscriber Content [...]"

You would need to ask a lawyer.

@testing-for-ya CC licenses are revocable from someone who breaches the terms, which is presumed in the OP. As KevinB comments, that breach would also be up to a lawyer to make a case for.

@testing-for-ya Okay, but you didn't comment "nobody has breached the terms and a profile statement isn't going to auto-revoke", you said "there are no take-backsies"; that's mostly true, but not quite, and that's what I responded to. Whether anyone has breached anything, the OP says clearly "I am expecting...the company will breach", and is asking about what comes after that. In their scenario, your statement "no take-backsies" is false.

@testing-for-ya How the license is breached would not affect the procedures that follow, and OP doesn't suggest someone else breaches the license but SE itself. My non lawyer understanding is the same as AMtoo's which is that nothing needs to be done to trigger the revocation (it's automatic if the terms are breached) but nonetheless legal action may be necessary to enforce it. The only entity that needs to be convinced is a court, if it goes that far.

@testing-for-ya Okay, OP did not ask "is (some particular behavior) a breach of the CC-BY license" so I'm not sure why we should litigate an unknown and unstated behavior in the comments.

On July 26, Stack Overflow updated the post to include different modifications to the CC BY-SA license than the prior version. This remains a breach of the license terms, as the CC BY-SA license does not allow additional restrictions, as previously outlined below in this answer and in other answers.

### I am not a lawyer; this isn't legal advice
As I wrote in my response to the recent Creative Commons Data Dump announcement, the CC BY-SA license contains text whereby when someone who breaches the license terms, the CC BY-SA license is automatically revoked for the person or entity in violation of the license terms. You don't have to do anything. Nothing you can put in your profile will change those terms.
If/when the company breaches the terms of the license you granted by accepting the site TOS, you would then have the full, legal right to take action and demand resolution. I can't say how to best take that action. Maybe the kind folks over at Law SE have advice to offer.
What do I plan to do?
I will likely first attempt to resolve the issue the way I would with any dispute: contact the Company, make a demand, and hope they are cooperative.
If the Company is not responsive, I will then escalate to something involving the legal system. Depending on where you live, that's going to look different... For non-US users, that also involves the complication of venue--Does a German user leverage the US or German legal system? Different laws and enforcement mechanism make for very unique decisions.
There's really another big wrinkle: a license violation related to the Data Dump affects every creator who has contributed to the site and has content in the dump. If enough users come forward to a willing legal team, a large scale violation may result in a class action lawsuit, whereby many different cases are combined into a single case to attempt to recover damages.

Or in other words, you say it would be possible to "sue their $$$", which means making them understand through money - and that might actually work.

@ShadowWizard . I guess that's a very concise way of saying it, yes. I'm still holding out hope it doesn't get as far as that.

Maybe tomorrow, I'll convert all my answers into pages on my website, so I can work on getting any inbound links updated to a more permanent home.

" If enough users come forward to a willing legal team, a large scale violation may result in a class action lawsuit" count me in.

426 answers - good luck with that! :-)

I'm thinking I might be able to use SEDE to generate markdown that I can then just copy/pasta into Wordpress. We'll see how I do when I give it a shot later today. :)

@ShadowWizard I created a little proof of concept for my contributions on cooking.stackexchange, serving them up over at https://cooking.am2.co. More work to do on a few fronts, but it's not going to be too difficult.

Awesome! But [tag:bug] report: index should be on top. :-D

@AMtwo If you put your content on Codidact, you won’t have to self-host it. ;)

@andreas, sure, but self-hosting isn't a concern for me. My ultimate plan is to merge it into an existing site

@AMtwo FYI there's Stack Exchange Backup and other related projects as noted in the README that could output one's contributions on the Stack Exchange network as source text to aid in content migration.
